# Optimizing Django+scikit svm model

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

I am building a django app facilitating scikit SVM inference. Currently the svm model was built offline and has been placed inside the Django site.

The problem is the every user request has to load the svm model prior to classification. And this response was terribly slow.

I am planning to load the svm model in memory to speed up classification as loading should be done just 1 times.

Currently, I have a few options,

1. Load the svm model in the Django in settings.py (I dont know how to do this as I have no idea how to pass the global variables)
2. Load the svm model into session (I am curious if this works as the model files are roughly 30MB)
3. Using cache (haven't tried it out yet)

So far, I have worked on the classification part and the Django things just frustrated me to dead.